# Subscribe to a topic and trigger two Callback functions

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to trigger two Callback functions by same message data. And to be able to execute Callbacks at the same rate as publication happens. At the moment I have it with following initialization code. What would be the correct way to do it?

```
ImuSubscriber = nh.subscribe ("/mikrokopter/fc_debug", 100, &MikrokopterControl::mikoImuCallback, this);

HeightSubscriber = nh.subscribe ("/mikrokopter/fc_debug", 100, &MikrokopterControl::heightCallback, this);
```

The goal is to call two different Callbacks as far as i understood. I want the published message data into two different functions and they to be executed when ever new data is available from publisher.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35814/subscribe-to-a-topic-and-trigger-two-callback-functions/) by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-06-06**:
Are you trying to call the same callback two times or to call two different callbacks?

**Comment by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on 2012-06-06**:
I modified the question a bit, hope it's more clear now

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-06**:
Interesting questions... hope to see some answers from pros.. :)

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-06-06**:
You still seem to be providing the same function in both callbacks. Additionally, I don't fully understand why you need multiple callbacks. Is there a reason you cannot call multiple functions with the message data from a single callback?

**Comment by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on 2012-06-06**:
No special reason, basically were wondering about if there are some sophisticated ways to do this with ROS. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simplest solution to do what you're trying to do is to simply call two functions within a "generic" callback function:

```
ImuSubscriber = nh.subscribe ("/mikrokopter/fc_debug", 100, &MikrokopterControl::genericCallback, this);

...

void MikrokopterControl::genericCallback(const sensor_msgs::IMU& data)
{
    function1(data);
    function2(data);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

you can use mutiple thread to run them. at firt, you init the two thread. when the callback is triggered, it will wake the two threads to run one time.